# Trouble setting up Ambari host from Ambari server wizard

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed Ambari server and am using the wizard to setup an agent. It is failing to recognize the

```
==========================
Running setup agent script...
==========================

Command start time 2019-08-19 22:35:34
Host registration aborted. Ambari Agent host cannot reach Ambari Server 'localhost:8080'. Please check the network connectivity between the Ambari Agent host and the Ambari Server

Connection to ingest-1.testserver.com closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=ingest-1.testserver.com, exitcode=1
Command end time 2019-08-19 22:35:34

ERROR: Bootstrap of host ingest-1.testserver.com fails because previous action finished with non-zero exit code (1)
ERROR MESSAGE: Connection to ingest-1.testserver.com closed.

STDOUT: Host registration aborted. Ambari Agent host cannot reach Ambari Server 'localhost:8080'. Please check the network connectivity between the Ambari Agent host and the Ambari Server

Connection to ingest-1.testserver.com closed.
```

The Ambari server is on master.testserver.com. I have the FQDN setup in the `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` files and see the correct FQDN when I run `hostname -f`.

These exact server name are not the actual subdomains or domains, but represent the situation correctly. For some reason the agent is trying to reach back to the server as localhost instead of the FQDN of the Ambari server.

Answer (score 0):

I knew this was a networking problem, but it took me a bit to figure out exactly what the problem is. It had something to do with how our default server initialization scripts work.

On master.testserver.com the `/etc/hosts` file looked like this.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 master.testserver.com
198.85.79.75 master.testserver.com
45.65.103.45 ingest-1.testserver.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

On ingest-1.testserver.com the `/etc/hosts` file looked like this.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 ingest-1.testserver.com
45.65.103.45 ingest-1.testserver.com
198.85.79.75 master.testserver.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

On both of these all of the lines but the two public IP address lines where setup by our server initialization scripts. The two lines with the public IP address where added by the scripts I wrote for bootstrapping them to prepare for Ambari. On both servers, the two lines that list 127.0.0.1 and the machine's FQDN where the problems. After removing them and restart the ambari-server service on master solved the problem.